Count elements in a row and create column counter in pandas
I have created the following pandas dataframe:
import pandas as pd

ds = {'col1' : ['A','A','B','C','C','D'],
      'col2' : ['A','B','C','D','D','A']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)

The dataframe looks like this:
print(df)

  col1 col2
0    A    A
1    A    B
2    B    C
3    C    D
4    C    D
5    D    A

The possible values in col1 and col2 are A, B, C and D.
I need to create 4 new columns, called:

countA: it counts how many A are in each row / record
countB: it counts how many B are in each row / record
countC: it counts how many C are in each row / record
countD: it counts how many D are in each row / record

So, from the example above, the resulting dataframe would look like this:

Can anyone help me please?

Here is a way using pd.get_dummies()
df.join(pd.get_dummies(df,prefix='',prefix_sep='').T.groupby(level=0).sum().T.rename('count{}'.format,axis=1))

and here is a way using value_counts()
df.join(df.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack(fill_value = 0).rename('count{}'.format,axis=1))

Output:
  col1 col2  countA  countB  countC  countD
0    A    A       2       0       0       0
1    A    B       1       1       0       0
2    B    C       0       1       1       0
3    C    D       0       0       1       1
4    C    D       0       0       1       1
5    D    A       1       0       0       1


Probably this could work for you
from numpy import unique

for k in unique(df.values):
    df['count'+k] = df.eq(k).sum(axis=1)

which gives
  col1 col2  countA  countB  countC  countD
0    A    A       2       0       0       0
1    A    B       1       1       0       0
2    B    C       0       1       1       0
3    C    D       0       0       1       1
4    C    D       0       0       1       1
5    D    A       1       0       0       1


You can compare whole column with specific letter, convert booleans to int and sum such obtained series for each letter. For example:
import pandas as pd
ds = {'col1' : ['A','A','B','C','C','D'],
      'col2' : ['A','B','C','D','D','A']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)

to_count = ['col1', 'col2']
for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
    df[f'count_{letter}'] = sum([(df[col] == letter).astype(int) for col in to_count])

returns:
    col1 col2 count_A count_B count_C count_D
0   A   A   2   0   0   0
1   A   B   1   1   0   0
2   B   C   0   1   1   0
3   C   D   0   0   1   1
4   C   D   0   0   1   1
5   D   A   1   0   0   1


Keep it simple, you can stack+droplevel to get a Series, then crosstab to count and join the output, optionally after add_prefix to rename the columns:
# reshape to 1D
s = df.stack().droplevel(-1)

# count and add to original
out = df.join(pd.crosstab(s.index, s).add_prefix('count'))

Or using numpy broadcasting, which could be very fast if you DataFrame is large and you have a limited number of unique values:
cols = np.unique(df) # ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

df[[f'count{c}' for c in cols]] = (df.to_numpy()[...,None] == cols).sum(axis=1)

Output:
  col1 col2  countA  countB  countC  countD
0    A    A       2       0       0       0
1    A    B       1       1       0       0
2    B    C       0       1       1       0
3    C    D       0       0       1       1
4    C    D       0       0       1       1
5    D    A       1       0       0       1

